# Oracle arrangements

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have this issue, I have this table Locations{id,name}. In a query how can I get the number of different permutations two by two?

For example I have three locations:

- Portugal
- Spain
- UK

The combinations are

- Portugal,Spain
- Spain Portugal
- Portugal,UK
- UK,Portugal
- Spain,UK
- UK,Spain

So the returned value should be 6. I can't get my head around this problem.

Comment: Sounds like simple math to me - just 3 x 2 - 3 items with 2 degrees of freedom. You can work out numbers of combinations with multiplcation - for 4 items it should be 4 items with 3 degrees of freedom (4 x 3)

Comment: do you really want the number? that's just some permutation math - or do you want each pair returned as the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2 
FROM Locations t1, Locations t2
WHERE t1.name <> t2.name)
```

Here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41a10/3

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, if you just want the number, that's easy to do as it's just a math problem.

If you actually want all the combinations, you're looking for a cartesian product, except you want identical pairs filtered out.

See below -

```
with tbl as(
select '01' as id, 'Portugal' as name from dual union all
select '02' as id, 'Spain' as name from dual union all
select '03' as id, 'UK' as name from dual
)
select x.name, y.name
from tbl x, tbl y
where x.name <> y.name
```

Result:

```
NAME        NAME
Portugal    Spain
Portugal    UK
Spain       Portugal
Spain       UK
UK          Portugal
UK          Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to apply the right formula:

```
select count(*) * (count(*) - 1)
from locations l;
```

If you might have duplicates, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct name) * (count(distinct name) - 1)
from locations l;
```

The number of two-way combinations for n things is `n*(n - 1)`.  You would divide the above by `2` if pairs were the same regardless of order.